# Output data from multiple sources into separate rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am pulling data from multiple Excel files within a folder. It outputs all in one column. I wish to make each Excel file data-set its own column and transpose it into rows. How can I accomplish this within a sub?

My thought is that it has something to do with that last if statement (with comments 'set the destrange' and 'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange.'

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    Dim FirstCell As String

'FIND FOLDER *MAKE SURE TO ADD SLASH AT THE END
MyPath = "C:\Users\dube\Desktop\Test for Lease Comps\"

'IF THERE ARE NO EXCEL FILES
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'PULLING DATA FROM EXCEL FILES AND ADDING TO ARRAY
FNum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    FNum = FNum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
    MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Add a new workbook with one sheet
Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
rnum = 1

'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
If FNum > 0 Then
    For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

            On Error Resume Next

            With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                Set sourceRange = .Range("C6:C32")
            End With

            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Set sourceRange = Nothing
            Else
                'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                End If
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                Else

                    'Set the destrange
                    Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                    'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                    With sourceRange
                        Set destrange = destrange. _
                                        Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                    End With
                    destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                    rnum = rnum + SourceRcount

                End If

            End If                

            mybook.Close savechanges:=False

        End If

    Next FNum
    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't have time to answer fully, but your `destRange` is always assigned as column B, at the very least you'll need to increment that using `Offset` method (or some other approach using a loop counter).  This way, each pass will go successively in column C, D, etc.

Comment: Ok that helps. Where/how would I add that?